# Storing common files in texmf - MacOS

Tags: texmf

I have a number of files that I include in various latex documents (using `\include`). I thought the best way to keep them in one location would be to put them in a directory under `~/Library/texmf`. If I put it right under `texmf` (`~/Library/texmf/Common_stuff`) they are not found (even after running `texhash`). If I put them under `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` it complains that it cannot write the `.aux` files in that directory. Is there a way of making this work? I am using texlive.

Thanks.

Comment: For common stuff you should use `\input`, not `\include`.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to use  `\includeonly` so `\input` won't work. I don't think that is the problem I am trying to solve anyway -- `\input` will give the same error.

Comment: Quite strange common stuff, then. What do you have there?

Comment: Each of the frames in my beamer presentations are in a different file and then I include them in various presentations and depending on length, I exclude some of them. I would like to maintain these files in a common place.

Comment: also what are you using as the argument to `\include` you should just use the file name (not the full path) then the aux files will be written to the current directory.

Comment: I will try it with that. I was also trying to respond to Blumsohn's answer below, but it won't let me add a comment to it. I wanted to say that using Tex Live Utility, under Actions I do not see Update Filename Database. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\include` and `\includeonly` is the wrong approach, in my opinion.

If your files are in `TEXMFHOME` (for TeX Live this means below `~/texmf/tex/latex`, unless one is using MacTeX, where it becomes `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex`), you don't need to call them by complete path.

Then it's easy to create commands that do similarly to `\include` and `\includeonly` without creating `.aux` files and issuing `\clearpage`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\commoninclude}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_ozsu_common_include_clist { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\commoninput}{m}
 {
  \clist_if_in:NnT \g_ozsu_common_include_clist { #1 }
   {
    \input{#1}
   }
 }
\clist_new:N \g_ozsu_common_include_clist
\ExplSyntaxOff

\commoninclude{a,b,d}

\begin{document}

\commoninput{a}

\commoninput{b}

\commoninput{c}

\end{document}
```

This will just input `a.tex` and `b.tex`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll study this a bit more, but I think I get the gist of it.

Comment: @ozsu I just define a list containing the file names you want to load for this particular task (the list is modifiable. At each `\commoninput` command, we check whether the requested file is in the list.

Comment: Yes, I used it and it works great and does what I wanted without creating far too many .aux files. Many thanks.